# Best tool for a beginner in Constraint Logic Programming

Tags: constraint-programming, logic-programming, clp

I need to create a prototype application for production order scheduling for my university.

I am still new to the topic of CLP and I am looking for an easy tool/environment/system that will let me define logic for few machines (i.e. 5-10) with their succession, capacity, speed, changeover times, etc, define some production orders (with their parameters maybe the deadline, profit, delay penalty) and as a result return them in an optimized order.

As I am not experienced in the topic of CLP tools, could anyone recommend a good tool to create a prototype quickly? For now I have found many good opinions about ECLiPSe but I really could use an opinion from someone working with CLP.

Comment: To start with, stick to constraints over finite domains: There, you have several options: SICStus, SWI, B, ECLiPSe.

Comment: @false I would also recommend imperative constraint logic programming languages such as [Picat](http://picat-lang.org/). Picat makes it possible to write logic programs in an imperative style, so it may be more "beginner-friendly" than most other logic programming languages.